# Program with "5 10 20 40" pattern in Python without infinite "if" statements

Tags: python

**I want to make a python program where the user inserts a number**

If number < 5, it prints 0

If 5 < number < 10, it prints 1

If 10 < number < 20, it prints 2

If 20 < number < 40, it prints 3

If 40 < number < 80, it prints 4

If 80 < number < 160, it prints 5

If 160 < number .... and so on forever

The pattern is 5 10 20 40 80 160 320 640 1280...

I am pretty new to coding and I'm not sure how to do that, any help is appreciated.

Comment: How would you solve this mathematically with a pen on paper, and what is stopping you from implementing that in Python?

Comment: I think the question does make sense, you would like a mathematical formula that gives  a number based on the above logic, because obviously the input is not defined and you can't cover all the case using if

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar In fact I think this can be easily solved mathematically.

Comment: @DeepSpace I know that in mathematics its something like k = k*2, if the first k is 5. My limited experience and Python knowledge is stopping me from implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the concept of Geometric progression your function can be written as :

```
import math

def bucket(value):
    return math.ceil(math.log(value/5)/math.log(2))
```

where 5 is  first term of the sequence and the common ratio be 2.

Output :

```
bucket(321)
7
```

Comment: This works except for the values: 0, 1, 2.
I can solve it tho if I intend your code into an If statement. Thank you.

Comment: Yes that's because this is loge, can you add an extra corner condition for values less than 3 please def bucket(value):
   `if(value<3):
        return 0
    return math.ceil(math.log(value/5)/math.log(2))`